# What can i use instead of SPWebApplication in SharePoint 2003?

Tags: administration, web-application, 2003

I've discovered that class SPWebApplication doesn't exists in SharePoint 2003 API(Microsoft.SharePoint.dll, version 11, namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration). But is there any analog of it? How can i retrieve IsAdministrationWebApplication property for example? Or SharePoint 2003 doesn't contain such options at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [SPVirtualServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spvirtualserver.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you're looking for [AdminPortUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd585684%28office.11%29.aspx) property of the **SPWebServer** class, which is described as:

> The AdminPortUrl property of the SPWebServer class gets the URL for
>   the administration port of the Web server.